# problem to find out the string is null or not

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

in mysql default null value is (NULL)

when i try to use it in c# that code not work because it is a string who have a value "(NULL)"

how i can check that string is null or not. if i check by string.insnullorempty or ==null it's not worked

how can i check this row  is null or not in c#

Comment: Could not understand what you are asking here. Can you elaborate the issue?

Comment: Can you post the code that checks for a null and the code that returns the URL from the DB?

Comment: Are You sure You didn't get empty string from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if (dbval == System.DBNull.Value)

Comment: thanks but issue is solved now i can check using string.isnullorempty()

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you have some configuration problem (e.g. wrong SQL in 'create table' statement) for which mySql is returning you a string containing "(NULL)" instead of a null value?

Answer (score 1):

String.IsNullOrEmpty() - should help IMO...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so have you tried string.IsNullOrEmpty() or using a comparison like myValue == NULL?